# IE 11 Developer Tools - Focus in IFRAME?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

In the console of the Developer Tools in Chrome, the 'focus' can be changed to an IFRAME using the dropdown selector, shown here:

[image: Developer Tools in Chrome]

How can that be done in Internet Explorer 11, in the F12 Developer Tools?

(I know that the contents of IFRAMEs can also be accessed using `frames[0]...`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IE from versions 9 onwards you can use the cd() command in the console to change the frame targeting you need to pass in a reference to the frame.

```
cd(window.frames[0])
```

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx#UsingCDacrossFrames

Answer (score 3):

To move focus to the top window, use:

```
cd()
```

and to move to the first iframe, use:

```
cd(frame[0])
```

Seems like you **cannot** use `cd(top.frame[1])` to move to a sibling frame.  But if iframes are nested, can use `cd(frame[0])` to move into the first one, then `cd(frame[0])` again to move in the nested one.

It is nice that immediately after typing `cd(frame[x])` the console echos back: `Current window: www.server.com/path/page.aspx` showing you the current frame's source URL.